# MonetDB refresh data in background best strategy with active connections making queries

Tags: database, bigdata, monetdb

I'm testing MonetDB and getting an amazing performance while querying millions of rows on my laptop.

I expect to work with billions in production and I need to update the data as often as possible, let say each 1 minute or 5 minutes worst case. Just updating existing records or adding new ones, deletion can be scheduled once a day.

I've seen a good performance for the updates on my tests, but i'm a bit worried about same operations over three of four times more data.

About BULK insert, got 1 million rows in 5 secs, so good enough performance right now as well. I have not tried deletion.

Everything works fine unless you run queries at the same time you update the data, in this case all seems to be frozen for a long-long-long time.

So, what's the best strategy to get MonetDB updated in background?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could do each load in a new table with the same schema, then create a `VIEW` that unions them all together. Queries will run on the view, and dropping and recreating that view is very fast.

However, it would probably be best to merge some of these smaller tables together every now and then. For example, a nightly job could combine all load tables from the previous day(s) into a new table (runs independently, no problem) and then recreate the view again.

Alternatively, you could use the `BINARY COPY INTO` to speed up the loading process in the first place.

Comment: HI, really good approach! I was thinking on having several tables and "rename" the table after each refresh but yours sounds a really good. Thanks. BTW I'll let open the question for awhile.

Answer (score 2):

There is a new merge table functionnality that could replace the view in Hannes Mühleisen answer and would be more idiomatic.
You can attach / detach partitions using:

```
alter table mergedTable ADD/DROP table partitionTable
```

It will be problematic for updates as they must be made directly to the partition tables easier if you have a partitionning key (date/...)
But it was the same with the previous solution.

Comment: I've been reviewing documentation and looks quite good approach. Do you have any idea if there is any difference in performance between merge tables and views? Thanks in advance